# How to create a Django API using django rest framework which shows response from some external source?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

i am in a situation where i need to create a `django api` which on call from `frontend` gives a response fetched internally from some other source but not from `serializers` and `models`. Currently i am using django rest framework to create `api` like below

## MODELS

```
# Create your models here.
class submission(models.Model):
    # fixed fields to show on today panel/pending panel
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    email_sender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
        return self.email_id
```

## SERIALIZERS

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = submission
        fields = ('__all__')
```

## VIEWS

```
class SAMPLE(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = submission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

## URLS

```
router = DefaultRouter()
# user table
router.register('user_table_all_data', SAMPLE, basename='user_table_all_data')
```

and it works as charm , but in order to work with `django rest framework` i always need to call like this `1. Create model or use existing model,` `2. Create serializers,3. Create Views,4. Create URLs`,

But what if i dont want to use `models` say for example i want to show data from other source say which contains a sample `json` like below

```
sampleData = {"Name":"RAJNISH","Age":32,"ADDRESS":"India"}
```

so if my `API` is say 'sample/someid (not pk)'

returns response as

```
{"Name":"RAJNISH","Age":32,"ADDRESS":"India"}
```

how can i do this in django rest framework?

Comment: Better capitalize first letter of classes 'class Submission' 'class Sample'

Comment: if you getting data from third party just return json response of it instead of using drf serializer

Comment: @ Linh Nguyen can you provide a working code how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use Function based views instead of Class based views

```
def sample(request):
    return Response(data={"Name":"RAJNISH","Age":32,"ADDRESS":"India"})
```